# Why is the design of questions list so different between front page and All Questions page?

Tags: discussion, design, question-lists, homepage

There is a big inconsistency in the display of a questions votes/answers/views between the home page and the questions pages, as you can see:

[image]

As far as I can tell this is the same across all the network sites, so I assume this is just how it is output on different pages. I can see that this isn't just a styling issue and the underlying HTML structure is different. The horizontal layout on the frontpage does link to the question (which seems unnecessary to me?) while the other doesn't. Apart from that I can't see any other functionality differences.

Is there an actual design reason for this? I don't have a problem with the design of either layout and the difference doesn't cause any real issues but without any real functional differences I think there should be some consistency.

Comment: "big inconsistency"? It's as minor as different order of the first two questions. "Tiny inconsistency", perhaps, even smaller.

Comment: I disagree. I know it's not a big *issue*, but its definitely an *inconsistency*.. maybe not big, but its definitely more than tiny.

Comment: Downvote because I was expecting something like different score, answer count etc. What you see is simply two different views. They should not be the same to begin with. (Agree the different order is weird, but really minor)

Comment: The question says *design* inconsistency. Different scores etc wouldn't be a design inconsistency it would be data inconsistency. You say 'They should not be the same to begin with' ...why? That's exactly what i'm asking.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I've made the title somewhat more clear to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a feature to have a quick peek at the question at hand. By moving the votes, etc. there is more space to show the first lines of the question. (Opposed to the front page where you want to see more titles to see what is interesting)

In the new navigation, you can toggle *any view* to do the same. Just click the icon on the right above the view:

> [image: icons]

Just set it the way you like. It will remember this setting for the next time you open that view.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me ...I can't see the buttons though?

Comment: Maybe you are not enrolled in the new nav testing group.

Comment: Are we still testing it?

Comment: Aren't we? @Braiam